# Discussion or not? Advice on this question?

Tags: discussion

I want to post the following, am afraid it's a discussionable issue, and I want suggestions on how to edit it to fit Q&A

p.s.: The more I read it, I know it's a discussion issue, but in desperate need of an answer.

Q: How to handle new users requests? groups? roles? permission sets?

Text: Every time I get a request to create a new user, there are several followup questions I need to answer my self (or have the user's manager answer) so I can create the appropriate rights and relations for the new user.

There are : publie groups, profiles and roles the address. Not to mention Permisison sets and price books.

Any way in SF to address this multiple answer choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think questions like this can be on-topic for SFSE if asked if asked in ways that solicit specific approaches to this challenge (like Mike Chales) as opposed to general brainstorming.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your organization is like, but if I mentioned public groups, profiles, or roles to most of my users they'd have no idea what I'm talking about. Our system is that each group has a super-user/champion who makes the user requests to us. That user knows enough about SF and security model to answer most of those questions and we deal with additional permissions as the need arises. If you want a stock list of questions answered you could probably craft a survey for some basic information (maybe even a complex Flow if you're ambitious.)

Overall though, I don't see how you'd make this concrete enough for a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

How about trying to ask your question on the new success.salesforce.com site? The Collaboration section lends itself well to discussion.